# concatenation of variables in WHERE clause including "/"

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a package where get 3 different variables while invoking and based on those I am performing a SELECT statement in a DB table. Now since in that DB table, I dont have to searched based on a STRING by concatenating the input variables like

Suppose I got these 3 variables 
p_A
p_B
p_C

and in my where select statement I have perform a search like

```
Select * from TABLE_A where HTTPDATA like '%/p_A/p_B/p_c"
```

I need to have "/" included in my like statement because in DB column we have entries like 
/xxx/sss/aaa

Could you please tell me how to achieve this. I have tried adding || between all variables but still its not working.

Comment: `/` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-CONCATENATE-24.aspx

Comment: @Lashane  -  I have tried something like this in my where clause    WHERE HTTPDATA like '%CONCAT(/p_A/p_B/p_C)';    - but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sample table content

```
SQL> select * from test;

NAME
--------------------
/ab/cd/ef
```

Sample procedure

```
DECLARE
  P_A VARCHAR2(20):='ab';
  P_B VARCHAR2(20):='cd';
  P_C VARCHAR2(20):='ef';
  D VARCHAR2(20);
  C number(2);
BEGIN
  D:='%/' ||P_A|| '/' ||P_B|| '/' ||P_C;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO C FROM TEST WHERE NAME LIKE D;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count='||C);
END;
/
```

Output

```
count=1
```

Even you can do like this in the above procedure

```
SELECT COUNT(*) into c FROM TEST WHERE NAME LIKE '%/'||P_A||'/'||P_B||'/'||P_C;
```